# Inspect content of SLAB

Tags: linux, kernel, nss

Is there a way, preferably simple, how to inspect content of SLAB caches, especially *dentry* cache? I can imagine that this can be doable through kernel modules, but I *highly* doubt security would let me install custom-built kernel module to production system.

I'm 99% sure we're impacted by NSS dentry leak, but want to see cached entries to be 100% sure.

rhel, 2.6.32
nss-softokn-3.14.3-23.3.0.1.el6_8.x86_64

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Server Fault has covered this before: [Unusually high dentry cache usage](https://serverfault.com/q/561350/241174) which resulted in [RHEL bug 1044666, Can curl HTTPS requests make fewer access system calls?](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1044666)

Examining cache contents is not required. From the bug report, this is not a small amount objects in the cache, they got millions of them with just a few curl executions. Further, you can see it access files by tracing processes using NSS, looking at calls to access().  There should be a high volume of access to files that do not exist.

Set environment variable [NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE](https://dxr.mozilla.org/security/search?q=NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE) and retest. This env var needs to be set to "yes" or "no" to bypass file system speed tests, apparently. Excessive access to non-existent files should cease, and slab consumption stabilize.

---

In general, slab should not grow without bound.

Monitor this over time. For example, netdata collects slab by default. (Although, export it to a time series database with more retention to see trends over days and weeks.)